# Google Apps Script to set shape color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I was looking through the Google Apps Script reference [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/fill#setSolidFill(Color)) and noticed there is a method for `setSolidFill(color)`.

I was wondering if it was possible to write a Google Apps Script to set shape colors based on values/ lookup reference in a Google Sheet? Essentially set the colour of Shape #001 in Google Slides to the HEX code in A2 of a Google Sheet?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the detail of `write a Google Apps Script to set shape colors based on values/ lookup reference in a Google Sheet` and `Essentially set the colour of Shape #001 in Google Slides to the HEX code in A2 of a Google Sheet?`? And also, what is `Shape #001`?

Comment: Your link doesn't point to such a method

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks I've updated the link to show what I was looking at

Comment: @Tanaike, I am wondering if it is possible to set shape colours based on colour codes found in a Google Sheet. This would save me time manually adjusting each colour every time new data comes in. I think there is a shape or object ID that I could use to set that shape's colour.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed 2 sample scripts. If those helped you understand for achieving your goal, I'm glad. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks Pattern 1 looks promising to me, but how do I find the objectID?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you want to retrieve the object ID, you can use `getObjectId()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getobjectid) For this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is possible to set shape colours based on colour codes found in a Google Sheet.

I think that your goal can be achieved. So in order to help to understand about the method for achieving your goal, I proposed the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the color of shape is changed using the object ID of the shape in 1st slide on Google Slides. In this sample, the hex color is retrieved from the cell "A1" of the Spreadsheet. Please set the Spreadsheet ID, sheet name and the presentation ID.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const objectId = "###";  // Please set the object ID.
  
  const hexColor = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetId").getSheetByName("sheetName").getRange("A1").getValue();
  const slide = SlidesApp.openById("presentationId").getSlides()[0];
  var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == objectId);
  if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill(hexColor);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the color of shape is changed using the shape type of the shape in 1st slide on Google Slides. In this sample, the hex color is retrieved from the cell "A1" of the Spreadsheet, and the color of "RECTANGLE" shapes are changed. Please set the Spreadsheet ID, sheet name and the presentation ID. Please select the shape type from [Enum ShapeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape-type).

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const shapeType = "RECTANGLE";  // Please set the shape type.
  
  const hexColor = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetId").getSheetByName("sheetName").getRange("A1").getValue();
  const slide = SlidesApp.openById("presentationId").getSlides()[0];
  var objs = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getShapeType() == SlidesApp.ShapeType[shapeType]);
  if (objs.length > 0) {
    objs.forEach(obj => obj.getFill().setSolidFill(hexColor));
  }
}
```

### Note:

- These are the simple sample scripts. So when you use the script, please modify it for your actual situation.

### References:

- [setSolidFill(hexString)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/fill#setsolidfillhexstring)
- [getObjectId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getobjectid)
- [getShapeType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getshapetype)
- [Enum ShapeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape-type)

### Added 1:

When you want to retrieve the object IDs of all shaped in a slide, you can use the following script.

#### Sample script:

```
const slide = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides()[0];
const objectIds = slide.getShapes().map(s => s.getObjectId());
console.log(objectIds)
```

- In this case, the object IDs of all shapes in 1st slide are put in an array.

### Added 2:

For example, when the colors of all shapes in the 1st slide in Google Slides are changed to the red color, the following script can be used. When you want to select one of shapes using the object ID, at first, please retrieve the object IDs using the script of "Added 1", and use the script of "Pattern 1".

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const hexColor = "#ff0000";  // This is a red color.
  const slide = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides()[0];
  const shapes = slide.getShapes();
  if (shapes.length > 0) {
    shapes.forEach(obj => obj.getFill().setSolidFill(hexColor));
  }
}
```

### Added 3:

About `can the pattern 1 script use an array (I need to change colours of several shapes, not just one)`, from your additional request of `can you please show me how to adjust the pattern 1 script to work with an array?`, I added one more sample script as follows.

In this sample, at first, please set the object IDs and hex colors in `objectIds`. By this, the colors of shapes of 1st slide can be changed.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const objectIds = [
    {objectId: "###", hexColor: "###"},
    {objectId: "###", hexColor: "###"},
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ];
  
  const slide = SlidesApp.openById("presentationId").getSlides()[0];
  const shapeObjects = slide.getShapes().reduce((o, s) => Object.assign(o, {[s.getObjectId()]: s}), {});
  objectIds.forEach(({objectId, hexColor}) => {
    if (shapeObjects[objectId]) shapeObjects[objectId].getFill().setSolidFill(hexColor);
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it for your actual situation.

Comment: sorry, how do i use this in Google Apps Script?

Comment: @DrPaulVella Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `how do i use this in Google Apps Script?`. If you want to run the script, please do the following flow. 1. Create new Google Slides and create a shape (for example, it's rectangle.) 2. Open the script editor at the Google Slides. 3. Copy and paste the above script. 4. Run the function with the script editor by selecting the function name. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

Comment: @DrPaulVella I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `how do i use this in Google Apps Script?`. So I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? In that case, the colors of all shapes in the 1st slide in Google Slides are changed to the red color. This was not useful for your situation. I apologize again.

Comment: @Tanakie, thanks I think I found the ObjectIDs, after running the script, in Google Apps Script I went to View > Logs

Comment: @DrPaulVella Thank you for replying. I could understand that you could retrieve the object ID. If your issue is still not resolved, please tell me. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: sorry for the delay in my response. Yes, this solution does work when I use a basic shape such as a rectangle. But I have 2 questions: first, can the pattern 1 script use an array (I need to change colours of several shapes, not just one). And the second, my shapes were drawn with the polyline tool, so the script doesn't work on those shapes

Comment: @DrPaulVella Thank you for replying. About 2 new questions, Q1: `can the pattern 1 script use an array (I need to change colours of several shapes, not just one)`. A1: Yes. Q2: `my shapes were drawn with the polyline tool, so the script doesn't work on those shapes`. A2: I cannot answer this because I cannot understand about your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, from your replying of `Yes, this solution does work when I use a basic shape such as a rectangle.`, your initial question was resolved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, the initial question was resolved. can you please show me how to adjust the pattern 1 script to work with an array?

Comment: @DrPaulVella Thank you for replying. About your additional request of `can you please show me how to adjust the pattern 1 script to work with an array?`, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it?