# Google Apps Script to set shape color in google slides

Tags: javascript

I have seen [Google Apps Script to set shape color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591228/google-apps-script-to-set-shape-color) but it's only for sheets, are there any for slides? My requirements are like to change all shapes (Doesnt matter cirlce or rectangle or etc) to be fill in a color! Thanks!